# Gatling simulation does not starts when it should

Tags: gatling, intellij-plugin, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

I am experience a new problem with my Gatling simulation.  When I run it from IntelliJ locally, it starts and then waits for 90 seconds before starting the simulation.  With TRACE, here is the console output:

```
16:57:07.171 [INFO ] i.g.h.e.HttpEngine - Warm up done
================================================================================
2019-02-08 16:57:10                                           5s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=0      KO=0     )
---- myScenario ---------------------------------------------------
[                                                                          ]  0%
          waiting: 1      / active: 0      / done: 0     
================================================================================
<continue waiting for 90 seconds...>
================================================================================
2019-02-08 16:58:35                                          90s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=0      KO=0     )
---- myScenario ---------------------------------------------------
[                                                                          ]  0%
          waiting: 1      / active: 0      / done: 0     
================================================================================
16:58:35.966 [DEBUG] i.g.h.c.HttpCaches - HTTP/2 disabled
Simulation com.test.MySimulations started...
16:58:36.301 [TRACE] i.g.app.Runner - Asking Controller to start
```

Once simulation starts, which is just 1 HTTP request, it completes successfully without problems.

**So my question is what is causing the 90s delay between warm up done and simulation started?**

If it matters, here is the pom.xml:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
                <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```